# Interrupt back-propagation in branched neural networks

Tags: keras, backpropagation

I've a neural network that looks something like this.

```
input_layer_1            input_layer_2
      |                        |
      |                        |
  some_stuff           some_other_stuff
      |                       /|
      |     _________________/ |
      |    /                   |
   multiply                    |
      |                        |
      |                        |
   output_1                 output_2
```

Is there any possibility to cut the connection between `some_other_stuff` and `multiply`during back-propagation? I was thinking of `dropout` but this also applied during forward-propagation

So during back-propagation it should be like two networks:

```
 input_layer_1            input_layer_2
      |                        |
      |                        |
  some_stuff           some_other_stuff
      |                        |
      |                        |
      |                        |
   multiply                    |
      |                        |
      |                        |
   output_1                 output_2
```

Output_1 errors only influence weight adjustment in the left part of the network and Output_2 errors only on the right part.

I'm using keras with tensorflow so maybe there are some functions/Layers that achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wonders, you could use K.gradient_stop() inside a Lambda-Layer